# Create JWT token without signature?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, digital-signature

Is it possible to create JWT tokens without signature?

We have a case where we would not need the signature, but all the rest of the token would be needed. So is it possible to create the JWT token without the signature?

Based on the documentation, you create the token by:

```
var token = jwt.sign
```

command, so it kind of implies that the secret is compulsory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-6):

> To support use cases in which the JWT content is secured by a means
> other than a signature and/or encryption contained within the JWT
> (such as a signature on a data structure containing the JWT), JWTs
> MAY also be created without a signature or encryption.  An Unsecured
> JWT is a JWS using the "alg" Header Parameter value "none" and with
> the empty string for its JWS Signature value, as defined in the JWA
> specification [JWA]; it is an Unsecured JWS with the JWT Claims Set
> as its JWS Payload.

Since you didn't mention which library you're using, I suppose you are using the one [from auth0](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken). Although I haven't tested it yet, it seems that setting `algorithm` to `none`, causes "No digital signature or MAC value":

```js
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, cert, { algorithm: 'none'});
```

Comment: Does this mean you can create it without signature, or not?

Comment: @VilleMiekk-oja so says the documentation! > No digital signature or MAC value